# Is it possible to write into specific mipmap level in fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have created a classic 2D a texture, and rendered into some values, in my case depth. In the c++ code I use the `glGenerateMipmap()` function to auto generate mipmaps. In fragment shader I can access the texture, like a normal sampler2D uniform, and I would like to write into the given mipmap level, specifically I want to calculate values on r+1 level, according to values on level r, and write in it. Is there some useful tool to achieve that? Using GLSL 4.30

For example:

```
// That's how I get the value, I need some kind of method to set
float current_value = textureLod(texture, tex_coords, MIP_LVL).y;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use the function `glFramebufferTexture2D` and on the last parameter specify the mipmap level.

After you attached everything you need, render the image you want to be at the specific mipmap.

Note: Don't forget to change to `glViewport` so it will render to the appropriate mipmap size!

Here is a simple example:

```
unsigned int Texture = 0;
int MipmapLevel = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &RBO);
glGenTextures(1, &Texture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, TextureWidth, TextureHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
// glTexParameteri here

// Use shader and setup uniforms

glViewport(0, 0, TextureWidth, TextureHeight);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, TextureWidth, TextureHeight);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture, MipmapLevel); // Here, change the last parameter to the mipmap level you want to write to
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Render to texture

// Restore all states (glViewport, Framebuffer, etc..)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to modify a generated mipmap (generated with `glGenerateMipmap` or externally), you can use the same method, use `glFramebufferTexture2D` and choose the mipmap you want to modify.

After you have done all the setup stuff (like the above sample), you can either completely render a new mipmap, or you can send the original texture, and modify it in the fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This approach writes into mipmaps when it creates them and uses c++. Is it possible to modify the auto generated mipmaps in Fragment shader? (Updated my question)

Comment: "(You will need a Render buffer and a Frame buffer attached of course)." Why? There is absolutely no need to use a render buffer (or a depth buffer at all) in this scenario.

Comment: @derhass I have edited the answer, if there is something else please edit it or let me know :)

Comment: Thank you, with a little tweak I managed to generate mipmaps, and even modify the texture filtering in shader.